# Is it appropriate to add a tag that applies to the accepted answer rather than the question?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

In the [question posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637705/125871) the OP uses suitable tags for the question, namely `tikz-pgf`, `tikz-arrows`, `graphs`.

The accepted answer (mine) uses `tikz-cd`. Is it appropriate to add the `tikz-cd` tag to the question? The use of `tikz-cd` in the answer is somewhat atypical (for beginners), using nodes for cells, so I thought the tag might be helpful from a search perspective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general position has always been that tags are about questions, not answers. So tagging because an answer (accepted or not) uses a particular package has not been regarded as desirable.

Comment: While I agree with you in general and in principle, I do think there are times that a tag has been omitted only because the questioner does not fully understand the scope of his or her own question.  In such cases, it may make sense to add a tag associated with the *natural* answer to the question.

Answer (score 8):

Occasionally there are answerers that put a tag at the start of an answer, as a visual way of saying "This answer uses such-and-such package or technique". Stack Exchange has markdown for that.

For example, `[tag:tikz-cd]` looks like [tikz-cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-cd). This button is also a link to all the questions with this tag, i.e., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-cd. On the main page this also shows the tag excerpt on mouseover. For Meta the equivalent (with a link and mouseover) is `[meta-tag:tagname]`, for example [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging).

I couldn't find any guidance on TeX.Meta or on Meta.SE if this is a good idea, but personally I find it helpful to add such a tag in case you use an approach that the asker did not know about, or an approach using a different package than mentioned in the question (which is perfectly valid by itself).

Your answer would look for example like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

The other answer could then similarly be tagged [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks).