# Tagging answers

Tags: feature-request, tagging, answers

What do you think about adding tags to answers?

E.g. for this one [Songs Package lyrics printed in two columns, title and song information across the two columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661315/songs-package-lyrics-printed-in-two-columns-title-and-song-information-across-t) I suggested switching the package used. So it would be natural, in my view, to tag my answer, e.g. with **leadsheets** and perhaps **multicol**, as these are part of the proposed solution.

It would feel unatural to me adding those to the question, as the TO didn't know about or ask for those.

No idea whether or not this would spoil a tag-search, or if it's useful to allow searching tags in questions, answers or both.

A consequence would certainly be, and it might be useful, that frequently used or healthy approaches in solutions can become more prominent over time.

Comment: see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8928/36296

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 2):

The StackExchange interface doesn't consider tagging of answers; tagging is only connected to questions. Questions are the primary driver for the answers. Even if you search for (say) [answers tagged `tikz-pgf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btikz-pgf%5D) (`is:answer [tikz-pgf]`), the results will return *answers* associated with *questions* that are tagged with `tikz-pgf`.

It's really not advised to tag a question with something that was used in an answer, because questions may be generic in nature and have a diverse set of answer utilizing a variety of packages/concepts. As an odd example, someone asks about formatting a list, and an answer uses [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to provide the necessary formatting. The question should not be tagged with [enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumitem).